# Delete multiple items with the same name?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am adding "n" number of circles on the scene.

```
var radius = 1; 
var segments = 32; 
var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments); 
function generateCircles(){
  //scene.remove(circle);
  var count=0;
  while (1000> count) {
    circle = new THREE.Mesh (circleGeometry, material);
    scene.add (circle);
    count ++;
  }
}
```

Is it effective to do it this way?.

In my code I call this function, and every time you call it, it all goes back slower, I guess it's because there are more objects in the scene. What can I do?

Each time the function is called, I need to completely erase from the memory stage the circles that were generated.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8oxsxtc/

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: @invot yes! http://jsfiddle.net/v8oxsxtc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to move or change the circles after adding them to the scene, it would be more efficient to merge them all into one Mesh and add them to the scene as one Mesh. Then, you can simply remove that one Mesh from the scene before generating more circles:

```
var radius = 1; 
var segments = 32; 
var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments); 
var circlesMesh;

function generateCircles() {
  if (circlesMesh) { scene.remove(circlesMesh); }
  circlesMesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, material);
  var count = 0;
  while (count++ < 999) {
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(circlesMesh, new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, material));
  }

  scene.add(circlesMesh);
}
```